# Speed of comparing vs. setting variables

Tags: c, performance

is there a speed difference between "setting a variable" and "setting a variable after checking condition"?

So is it better to use

```
    if (state != IDLE) {
       state = IDLE;
    }
```

instead of

```
    state = IDLE;
```

?

In the first case, checking the flag takes some time. But can this duration be compared to the second case (simply setting a variable)? 
Which one is faster in general?

Thanks,
Martin

edit: The programm will run on a microcontroller (NXP LPCXpresso 1769) with 120 MHz inside an IRQ handler that receives CAN messages. The reason I'm asking is because I don't want the IRQ handler to handicap normal programm execution.

Comment: Is this even a performance bottleneck?

Comment: It depends on if the write to the RAM is faster or slower than reading from RAM AND doing a conditional operator,

Comment: (@Mysticial it shouildn't be in general...)

Comment: With any modern compiler, I would hope that they should be optimised to the same machine code.  AT any rate, this is such a tiny micro-optimization, and so platform-dependent, that I'm voting to close as "Not a real question"...

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it in a real program and tell us? As @OliCharlesworth points out, your toy example can probably be optimised out, and even if your had an example that couldn't trivially be elided, it would depend on platform, architecture, and lots and lots of context.

Comment: Except for the extra memory fetch that will be needed (but it could be prefetched, at virtually no additional cost), the problem with conditional jumps is their effect on the instruction pipeline and the "branch prediction" needed. (I don't know if this effect is as large on a NXP as it is on an x86).

Comment: @Mysticial: True that we should all avoid micro-optimizations until they are shown to be needed, but we should also know what our code is doing.  As wildplasser said, this question goes into various subjects (branch prediction, conditional instructions, prefetching, how the CPU cache works in general).  OP, I would read through [the paper here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals), good stuff.

Comment: as @EdS feels it is inappropriate to leave an answer describing programming style to your perf related question, I feel compelled to mention that this is bad style, because the code is semantically equivalent, and this would be noted in any basic CS course.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that in most cases, just writing the value will be at least as fast, and frequently faster than testing first.

A more detailed explanation: except for *very* low-end microcontrollers, the memory bus will normally be decopuled from the core. When you test first, the CPU has to write an address out to the memory bus, then wait for the memory to respond, before it can actually look at the value.

When you do the write, the CPU will typically just put the address/value into a write queue, then move onto the next instruction. Although there *is* a memory transaction involved, executing other instructions won't wait for it to complete (unless one them reads that value -- in that case, it'll depend on whether the CPU has a cache or not; if it does, it'll read teh value from the cache with minimal delay, but otherwise it'll typically wait for it to be written to memory then read it back in).

Answer (score 1):

**Theoretically:**

Your first example has two operations,

1. check the state
2. Modify the state

Your second example has one operation,

- Modify the state

So mathematically/logically, obviously first example is faster than second since there is one less operation to be performed.

**Practically:**

Depending on the variable being used, a smart compiler may optimize both first example and second example to generate same assembly instructions.
So both might have same performance.

**Exact determination:**

***Profile*** your application/code by using both by ***using representative data sets*** and only then can you get a proper picture and a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first fragment involves 'read, compare, write' and the second is just 'write', unoptimized code will be quicker for the second than the first because there are fewer options.  If the variable is qualified with `volatile`, the first must be slower than the second.  If the variable is not qualified with `volatile`, the compiler could optimize the first to the second since the result of the two sequences would be identical, regardless of what was in the variable before the assignment.